# An unsatisfying editing experience

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, review

I was asked to check a proposed edit of a question. I rejected the edit, saying "The original question makes no sense but is at least grammatical. The proposed edit is ungrammatical and still makes no sense. I understand neither and so will not attempt an improved edit." (Actually, a terse version of this to respect the character-count limit.) When I returned this, I received a reply telling me that the proposed edit had been accepted, but inviting me to edit the post directly.

This is not the first such experience. If it happens again, I will be inclined to ignore further requests to check editing. I think it a shame, though, if the system discourages good editors and encourages bad ones.

**Edit:** Well, a similar thing did happen again, with the same robotic message popping back immediately. Sadly, I now think that there are better uses of my time than responding to invitations to edit questions on this site.

Comment: Sounds like [robo-approvers are killing your will to review edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/155561/251274)...

Comment: I wish naming and shaming (followed by hostile stalking) was a more publicly acceptable thing to do. On the other hand, if it *was* publicly acceptable then it would be less shameful to those being named. Or something.

Comment: @user1729 This thread could have a catalog of "edits that shouldn't have been approved", linked to their review records; this way the focus is on content, but the records still include user names...

Comment: @user127096 It is not the same as a full-scale harassment. Who reads meta anyway? Not me!

Answer (score 6):

As with many things on this site, you can flag for moderator attention:

Go to your [review history](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/875/john-bentin?tab=activity&sort=reviews), find the offending item, and flag it for the moderators indicating that you think someone is robo-approving.

The moderators will look at the flag and deal with them on a case-by-case basis.

---

If you think the proposed edit (that was approved) is actually too horrible, so horrible that it actually makes the question worse, you can opt to roll-back the revision.

Comment: I don't think this will show up in the review history: the OP's review was never completed as the suggested edit was meanwhile approved.

Comment: @ArthurFischer: ummm... I may have misunderstood the OP.

Comment: I have found the back-button on my browser will often get me back to the offending Review queue item.